# Need help on excel Formula

Tags: excel-2007

i have more than 30 columns and 500+ rows in my Excel.
i have Excel calculation for end 12 columns. which is same for all 500 rows. but i'm not able to track it  as i user some merged rows.

My calculation is using values of different columns in the same row .
Based on some conditions i merged some rows . 
My problem is since i merged some rows in the middle of 2 columns , tracking of the formula is not working properly.so everytime if any change i have to manually modify 500 rows od formula this is really taking loong time.
**Sample formula: **=IF(AND($B$7=0,$L$7=0),SUM((AD7*$L$2),(T7*$I$7),(Q7*$H$7)),0)**
In the above B and L are merged column values

can any one help me this?

Comment: It sounds like you need to stop merging cells. Why are you doing that?

Comment: That is customer requirement , user has  to select 5 items compulsory. the merged cells are used either to include the item or making the item as optional. so in some cases if they select first item they have to include next 4 . that is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I just track the formula for all 500+ rows and i used "Replace" functionality w.r.t merged cell to update formula accordingly